# Firebase return always null

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) library, and I'm trying to preform a Real-Time Streaming from my Firebase Database. The problem is that the object returned from the database is null.
Would appreciate help!
Here's the code:

```
public class FirebaseManager
{
    FirebaseClient firebase;
    IDisposable observable;
    public event EventHandler newMessage;


    public FirebaseManager()
    {
        firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://yatmal-confessions.firebaseio.com/");

    }
    public void StartListening()
    {
        observable = firebase
              .Child("confessions")
              .AsObservable<Message>()
              .Subscribe(m => newMessage(m, null));
    }
 }
```

The Message Class:

```
public class Message
    {
        private string Time;
        private string Confessions;

        public Message()
        {
            Time = null;
            Confessions = null;
        }

        public string time { get => Time; set => Time = value; }
        public string confession { get => Confessions; set => Confessions = value; }
    }
```

The WPF code that should get the data and work on it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    FirebaseManager firebase;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        firebase = new FirebaseManager();
        firebase.newMessage += newMessage;
        firebase.StartListening();
    }

    void newMessage(Object obj, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Message message = obj as Message;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tb.Text += message.confession + "\n"));
        MessageBox.Show("End");
    }
}
```

}
The Object in the "newMessage" function is always contains Null message.
Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

the Database:

[image: firebase database]

Comment: Is confessions a string or is it a more complex object?

Comment: @jdweng
Every confession looks like this:

**confession:** some text
**time:** Timestamp

Comment: Looks like you are getting a response since you have 21 confessions. Do the plus signs open?  Are the details in attributes?  the link you provided says you need to use factories.

Comment: @jdweng I changed the image of the database in question, now you see the internal content of each confession.

Comment: @jdweng And what do "factories" mean?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library.  the results do no look like they are null.

Comment: @jdweng I added a screenshot. Maybe it will help?

Comment: Where are you sending a query to the database?  It looks like the type being returned is a Insert or Update.  If you are reading the database the type should be a Select.

Comment: @jdweng in the constructor of FirebaseManager class

Comment: You can't do it that way.  You need to register the newMessage (the +=)  before you send the query.  NewMessage receives the confessions.  So you are sending the query and not setup to receive the response.

Comment: @jdweng How should I do it?

Comment: Do not put the query in the constructor.  Create another method with the query and call after you register the event.

Comment: @jdweng I've changed, it still doesn't work ...
(I changed the code on the question, see)

Comment: I looks at the Firebase.Net site and don't see any examples like the code you are using.  I'm not sure if the Registering (+=) and the subscribe are both needed.  I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if the data is actually being returned.  You request may be bad.  Then once you know the data is in the response then start looking at the code.